# Логирование HTTP header'ов с JS

Tags: javascript, actionscript

Возможно ли записывать HTTP заголовки при помощи JavaScript? В частности интересует request header, а ответ уже не обязательно. Если возможно, то неплохо было бы знать как.
P.S не обязательно на javascript, главное что бы работало когда пользователь попадает на какой-нибудь сайт. Помимо JS еще есть Flash.

Comment: Это нужно для отладки?

Answer (score 1):

Отправляя запрос с помощью [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest), можно достать заголовки с помощью метода `request.getAllResponseHeaders()`:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'http://vk.com', false);
request.send(null);
var headers = request.getAllResponseHeaders();
```

Этот метод позволит обернуть все AJAX-запросы. Если вы используете какую-нибудь свою реализацию, то будет удобно. Но не все запросы словит.

Если у Вас есть доступ к серверу, проще будет непосредственно на сервере добавлять заголовки запроса в тело документа, а потом доставать его через js.

Comment: А можно ли что бы я модифицировал хеадер?)  Ну т.е пошлю запрос с другим user-agent'ом, а cookie уже подставлялись с браузера?